# How can I sum hours and minutes from a HH:MM time in two inputs in Javascript-Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I have two inputs that come from two inputs with the format hh:mm.

I would like to obtain the total number of hours spent.

```
GOOD
Example:
Input 1: 08:30
Input 2: 10:00
Total 1.5
```

In the following link you can see what I have tried to do, but the problem I am having is that it is not correctly subtracting the minutes at the time and instead of having the previous result I get this:

```
WRONG
Example:
Input 1: 08:30
Input 2: 10:00
Total 2.5
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n9h5ztef/2/

____EDITED_____
I'm sorry I explained myself badly.
I will try to put exactly what I have.
What I am trying to do is a sum of all the hours there are, there are two morning and afternoon shifts. I need to add all the hours.

This is a real example:

```
1st shift
input1: 08:30
input2: 10:00

2nd shift
input3: 16:00
input4: 18:00

Total hours: 3.5
```

In the first turn he has done 1.5 hours and in the second two hours. Total 3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply split on `:` change the minutes part to hours, and than calculate difference

```js
let getDifference = (time1, time2) => {
  let [h1, m1] = time1.split(':')
  let [h2, m2] = time2.split(':')

  return ((+h1 + (+m1 / 60)) - (+h2 + (+m2 / 60)))
}

console.log(getDifference("10:00", "08:30"))
```

***Note:-*** Don't forgot to change string to numbers before doing any arithmetic operations, here `+` is implicitly converting string to number

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will validate your answer, although unfortunately it does not work for my project, I set the example with only 2 inputs, but really there are four inputs total hours.

The total sum of hours of all inputs must be calculated.

Comment: @Sylar you should not accept answer if it doesn't solve the problem you specified in question, but you can extend the same idea for whatever number of inputs, it logic will still stays same, makes sense ?

Comment: Thanks @Code Maniac, but I try this similar operation but the result is incorrect when there are more inputs.

Comment: @Sylar seems to work fine [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/gtze7ock/), you can do similar

Comment: @Sylar you can separately find the difference for first half and second half, and than combine, where you're facing problem to extend this logic ?

Comment: I'm going to try, I've been doing tests but when discounting does not allow the sum, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
<input id="time1" value="08:30" size="5"> Time 1
<br>
<input id="time2" value="10:00" size="5"> Time 2
<br>
<button id="addTimes">Add times</button>
<br><br>Result <span id="timeSum">0</span>

<br>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  const timeToNumber = (time) => {
    const parts = time.split(':');

    const part1 = parseInt(parts[0]);
    let part2 = parseInt(parts[1]);
    part2 = part2 / 60;

    return part1 + part2;
  };

  $("#addTimes").on('click', function () {
    const time1 = $('#time1').val();
    const time2 = $('#time2').val();

    const result = timeToNumber(time2) - timeToNumber(time1);
    $('#timeSum').text(result);
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ruben, but I'm sorry my first example is wrong, I need four inputs and sum total hours.

Answer (score 1):

I made this code sometime back to calculate the hours worked from an in time and out time precisely to the minute. I modified it to work with two shifts.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var inTime2 = document.getElementById("in-time2").value;
  var outTime2 = document.getElementById("out-time2").value;

  var hoursIn2 = inTime2.split(':', 1);
  var hoursOut2 = outTime2.split(':', 1);
  var minutesArrayIn2 = inTime2.split(':', 2);
  var minutesArrayOut2 = outTime2.split(':', 2);

  var minutesIn2 = minutesArrayIn2[1];
  var minutesOut2 = minutesArrayOut2[1];

  var hoursToMinutesIn2 = hoursIn2 * 60;
  var hoursToMinutesOut2 = hoursOut2 * 60;

  var timeIn2 = hoursToMinutesIn2 + parseInt(minutesIn2);
  var timeOut2 = hoursToMinutesOut2 + parseInt(minutesOut2);

  var hoursWorked2 = (timeOut2 - timeIn2) / 60;

  var hoursInInt2 = parseInt(hoursIn2);
  var hoursOutInt2 = parseInt(hoursOut2);
  var minutesInInt2 = parseInt(minutesIn2);
  var minutesOutInt2 = parseInt(minutesOut2);
  var sumHours2;
  var sumMinutes2;

  if (minutesOut2 < minutesIn2) {
    var hoursOutInt3 = hoursOutInt2 - 1;
    var minutesOutInt3 = minutesOutInt2 + 60;

    sumHours2 = hoursOutInt3 - hoursInInt2;
    sumMinutes2 = minutesOutInt3 - minutesInInt2;

    document.getElementById("hours-worked2").innerHTML = sumHours2 + ":" + sumMinutes2;

  } else {
    sumHours2 = hoursOutInt2 - hoursInInt2;
    sumMinutes2 = minutesOutInt2 - minutesInInt2;

    document.getElementById("hours-worked2").innerHTML = sumHours2 + ":" + sumMinutes2;
  }

  var inTime = document.getElementById("in-time1").value;
  var outTime = document.getElementById("out-time1").value;

  var hoursIn = inTime.split(':', 1);
  var hoursOut = outTime.split(':', 1);
  var minutesArrayIn = inTime.split(':', 2);
  var minutesArrayOut = outTime.split(':', 2);

  var minutesIn = minutesArrayIn[1];
  var minutesOut = minutesArrayOut[1];

  var hoursToMinutesIn = hoursIn * 60;
  var hoursToMinutesOut = hoursOut * 60;

  var timeIn = hoursToMinutesIn + parseInt(minutesIn);
  var timeOut = hoursToMinutesOut + parseInt(minutesOut);

  var hoursWorked = (timeOut - timeIn) / 60;

  var hoursInInt = parseInt(hoursIn);
  var hoursOutInt = parseInt(hoursOut);
  var minutesInInt = parseInt(minutesIn);
  var minutesOutInt = parseInt(minutesOut);
  var sumHours;
  var sumMinutes;

  if (minutesOut < minutesIn) {
    var hoursOutInt1 = hoursOutInt - 1;
    var minutesOutInt1 = minutesOutInt + 60;

    sumHours = hoursOutInt1 - hoursInInt;
    sumMinutes = minutesOutInt1 - minutesInInt;

    document.getElementById("hours-worked").innerHTML = sumHours + ":" + sumMinutes;

  } else {
    sumHours = hoursOutInt - hoursInInt;
    sumMinutes = minutesOutInt - minutesInInt;

    document.getElementById("hours-worked").innerHTML = sumHours + ":" + sumMinutes;
  }

  var totalHoursTemp = sumHours + sumHours2;
  var totalMinutesTemp = sumMinutes + sumMinutes2;

  if (totalMinutesTemp >= 60) {
    totalHours = totalHoursTemp + 1;
    totalMinutes = totalMinutesTemp - 60;

    document.getElementById("total-hours").innerHTML = totalHours + ":" + totalMinutes;
  } else {

    document.getElementById("total-hours").innerHTML = totalHoursTemp + ":" + totalMinutesTemp;
  }

}
```

```css
.table-custom2 {
  padding: 12px 13px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-custom3 {
  padding: 12px 13px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="table-custom2">In Time</th>
    <th class="table-custom2">Out Time</th>
    <th class="table-custom2">Hours Worked</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="table-custom3"><input type="text" id="in-time1" class="input-xsmall" maxlength="5" oninput="myFunction()"></td>
    <td class="table-custom3"><input type="text" id="out-time1" class="input-xsmall" maxlength="5" oninput="myFunction()"></td>
    <td class="table-custom3"><span id="hours-worked"></span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="table-custom3"><input type="text" id="in-time2" class="input-xsmall" maxlength="5" oninput="myFunction()"></td>
    <td class="table-custom3"><input type="text" id="out-time2" class="input-xsmall" maxlength="5" oninput="myFunction()"></td>
    <td class="table-custom3"><span id="hours-worked2"></span></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<p>Total Hours Worked : </p><span id="total-hours"></span>
```